# Owl carousel loading all items in a vertical column. What am I missing here?

Tags: jquery, css, shopify, liquid, owl-carousel

I am setting up a recently viewed products script for Shopify, got the code from Github here: https://github.com/lucky110209/shopify-recent-viewed-products
I tried to make styles match my current theme, and place the recently viewed items inside an Owl carousel similar to the one in the "related products". The problem is that it shows all the items in a vertical line, please take a look at the store, I had to edit the link to reproduce the error in a non published theme copy, kindly see few products to build the recently viewed products carousel in the bottom of the product pages: https://alqamaru.com/?_ab=0&_fd=0&_sc=1&preview_theme_id=44568838215

I tried to change the owl carousel location, place it above the script, inside the {% raw %} tag, double-checked the section schema settings, tried to include the {% include 'product-card-grid' %} inside the raw tags, but it's not working, any help on fixing this will be appreciated.

recently-viewed.liquid:

````
{{ 'jquery.products.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{% assign column1 = section.settings.column1-rv | plus:0 %}
{% assign column2 = section.settings.column2-rv | plus:0 %}
{% assign column3 = section.settings.column3-rv | plus:0 %}
{% assign column4 = section.settings.column4-rv | plus:0 %}
{% assign column5 = section.settings.column5-rv | plus:0 %}
{% assign relateCol = 4 %}
{% assign relateLimit = section.settings.product_recent_limit | plus: 0 %}
{% assign currentProduct = product %}
<section class="section-related">
  <div id="related" class="related-products">
   <h3 class="detail-title font-ct"><strong><span>Recently Viewed Products</span></strong></h3>
   <div class="products-listing grid ss-carousel ss-owl">
    <div class="product-layout owl-carousel"
      {% if settings.enable_rtl %}data-rtl ="true"{% endif %}
      data-nav="{{ section.settings.recent_navigation-rv }}"
      data-margin    ="{{ section.settings.margin-rl }}" 
      data-lazyLoad    ="true"
      data-column1=" {{ column1 }}" 
      data-column2=" {{ column2 }}" 
      data-column3=" {{ column3 }}" 
      data-column4=" {{ column4 }}" 
      data-column5=" {{ column5 }}">
     <div id="recently-viewed-products" style="display:none"> 
     </div>
    {% raw %}
    <script id="recently-viewed-product-template"  type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
      <div class="item">
       <div id="product-${handle}">
              <div >
                {{if compare_at_price}}
                <span class="bt-sale">Sale</span>
                {{/if}}
                <a href="${url}">
                  <img src="${Shopify.Products.resizeImage(featured_image, "medium")}" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="${url}" title="${title}">${title}</a></h4>
                <p class="price">
                  <span class="price-new">${Shopify.formatMoney(price)}</span>
                  <span class="price-old">{{if compare_at_price}}${Shopify.formatMoney(compare_at_price)}{{/if}}</span>
                </p>
              </div>
       </div>
    </script>
    {% endraw %}
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var limit_product = {{ section.settings.product_recent_limit }};
  Shopify.Products.showRecentlyViewed( { howManyToShow: product_recent_limit } );
</script>
</div>
</section>```
````

Comment: Displays correctly in a horizontal row for me - have you tried different/the latest versions of browsers?

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking, I had to remove the carousel temporarily until fixed, kindly check the template copy here: https://alqamaru.com/?_ab=0&_fd=0&_sc=1&preview_theme_id=44568838215

Comment: When I check the console I see `product_recent_limit is not defined` from this line: `Shopify.Products.showRecentlyViewed( { howManyToShow: product_recent_limit } );` - I suppose the carousel isn't initialising because it's failing there.

Comment: I removed that variant and used the number '5' instead just to see if this will resolve the issue, now I don't see anything in the console, but still no luck. Thanks

Comment: One other thing I just noticed is there are a couple of slides with duplicate IDs: `id="product-new-vintage-ethnic-geometric-alloy-dangling-earrings-for-women"`, for example - is that something you have any control over?

Comment: I don't think so, because IDs should be different depending on what products you've seen, but normally it should not be duplicated, the problem is how to make the carousel render every element as a separate carousel item, just like in the recently viewed items, instead of loading everything as one element, here is another example I am looking to replicate: https://decorticademo.myshopify.com/ , kindly view few products and look at the bottom of a collection or product page to see how the recently viewed items are organized in the carousel. Thanks

Comment: Something else I've noticed is you're missing a closing `</div>` before the end of your script template block. Aside from that, I don't have time to keep trying to debug this, sorry. Good luck.

Comment: I've gone ahead, added the missing div tag, checked again, but unfortunately not working, thank you so much for taking the time to debug this issue, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MostaphaMarbouh can you try the below code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77936167/17891149

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this script

```
<script>
  var limit_product = {{ section.settings.product_recent_limit }};
  Shopify.Products.showRecentlyViewed( { howManyToShow: product_recent_limit } );
</script>
```

with below one

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
  var limit_product = {{ section.settings.product_recent_limit }};
  Shopify.Products.showRecentlyViewed( { howManyToShow: product_recent_limit } ); }, 5000); 
});
</script>
```